# desktop icon not showing

Tags: gnome, icons

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 and using it with gnome.
I can not see my computer icon, home folder icon in my desktop.
In Cinnamon settings the options to show them is enabled.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In `Advanced Settings`, go to `Desktop` in the left pane.  You can choose the options there.  If you do not have it installed, the packaged name is also known as gnome-tweak-tool.